# How to create a pseudo panel from a repeated cross-sectional dataset?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, causality

I am currently writing my Master thesis that focuses on the determinants of teenage pregnancy using a repeated cross-section from the Performance Monitoring for Action (PMA) project. It includes information since 2013 from 9 countries in Sub-Saharan Africa and 2 countries in Asia.

The main challenge is that the dataset I am using does not include unique IDs so one can not use panel data methods directly. However, I read that one could recreate Pseudo-Panels from Repeated Cross-Sections (Verbeek, Deaton, and Moffitt) by using cohorts or IVs where the instruments are dummy variables referring to the cohorts. My main concern is that I am not sure if I could make use of this approach given that the commonly used age cohorts would be too few in my case (as I am already restricting the sample for teenagers only) so I am afraid about biasing the results by losing variability and I also doubt the comparability of age cohorts (or any other type of cohorts) across different countries.

I would highly appreciate any feedback/literature you could provide on this or any other approach that could be applied to my specific problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Could you provide a full citation or a link to the research you mentioned?